# Software development cycle for a support team

Tags: project-management, project, agile

Could anyone please suggest a software process suitable to the work our team?

1. We are a team of 6 developers (mostly juniors).
2. We are supporting the ordering system for an online book store (similar to Amazon books).
3. The system is already online and functioning.
4. Most of the work is task based. Sometimes there is a bug that needs immediate fixing or a new module that needs to be added to the system.
5. Most of the time each developer is working on a separate module of bug which it's estimated time could range from few hours to few days.
6. Our customers (the management department) are located in another country (we are being outsourced) so requirements take a long time to verify or discuss.

You can view us mainly as a team of freelancers each waiting for a task to be handed to him. Sometimes if a big module is required 2 or 3 developers start working together on it, but that's when things starts going bad as we lack a well defined software process to adhere too.

Notes:

- The Waterfall model clearly fails in our case as our team is responsible for gathering the requirements, designing, coding and testing everything.
- We tried adopting Agile practices, but it was a complete failure mainly because of points 4, 5 & 6. There is no iteration or prototypes in our work.

So We are looking for a software process that can help us organize our work and provide an acceptable output.

Comment: Scrum 2?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh301772%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Or Kanban? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kanban_(development)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say you're mainly Juniors.  So, learn to walk before you try to run.  I suggest you try a *staged delivery model*.  And I also suggest you try reading this book:
[http://www.amazon.com/Software-Project-Survival-Guide-Practices/dp/1572316217](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1572316217)

Comment: well I'll look into the Staged Delivery Model and the book you recommended. Could you recommend a tool to use to help us in our work? We tried to use www.rallydev.com, but it was too complicated and it was mainly for agile teams. We need something simpler and more task oriented.

Comment: i cant up this enough! this book is absolutely vital and brutally good (old but precise!)

Comment: In my twenty-odd years of experience of software development, I've come to the conclusion that simple processes are the best.  Same with tools.  Keep it simple.  Staged Delivery necessitates that you need to be able to manage feedback from customers.  Borland StarTeam is a good tool in that it's (a) easy to use (b) easy to maintain and (c) has a good integrated change request platform.  
If you're using a Microsoft stack, then TFS is as good a choice as any.

Comment: PS:  make sure your tools support widely distributed teams, task branches and also treat change requests as configuration items.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using TFS Express, it's free and have Agile management tool, it's still beta, but Microsoft give a "Go Live" Tag so you can work with it and upgrade your work when RTM release
You can download it from here
http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/11/en-us/downloads#tfs-express

Answer (score 1):

I would Strongly Suggest RUP(Rational Unified Process)
Reason being

- Concurrent Phases can go on with part of team doing some phase whereas other developers working on a different thing
- You will follow RUP increments where some developer who finds solutions to bugs can move to next increment with a part of team still working on previous increment
- its highly adaptive and flexible and will help you a lot with different threads going on within project

Previously it was Closed source although IBM donated it to Open source in 2005 and 
here's a great presentation that will surely help you understand it better 
http://www.perftestplus.com/resources/rupfordummies_ppt.pdf

Hope it helps!!